# Float (Image) does not start from the top

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, positioning, subfloats

I am quite new to Latex and am using overleaf. As seen in the attached screenshot the left column figure starts from a bit down position compared to the table in the right column. This looks a bit weird for me.
I have tried positioning with the help of [t],[h],[ht],[!ht],[htbp!]... all yielding the exact same result. Any suggestions so as to finetune this gap?

```
\begin{figure} [!ht]%[htbp!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{grid_events2.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Reporting Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{grid_events} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{vmag.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{busVmag}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{vang.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{busVang}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{roc.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{ROC_phi}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[]{Simulated Grid Events and Associated Electrical Parameters}
\end{figure}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...Please keep your `MWE` always in an executable format....

Comment: Thank you. However, I did not understand your suggestion.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. This mean also not include  your own images in the MWE but "example-image" or others example images provided by the [mwe  package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe).

Comment: Wrap the command `\fbox{...}` around the `\includegraphics` commands (without intervening spaces, e.g. `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{grid_events2.pdf}}`. This will draw a box around the image such that you check whether the image itself contributes the white space. Probably unrelated, I'd remove the positioning argument `[b]` from the subfigures, since they aren't side by side anyway.

Comment: One potentially hacky solution (which is why I am not offering it as an answer) is to simply put a `\vspace{-1mm}` above the figure to move it up slightly.  The measurements can be adjusted, and other units are an option as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was waiting for better answers but I ended up doing manual manipulation using `vspace`.

Here is the code snippet.

```
\begin{figure} [!ht]%[htbp!]
\vspace{-15pt}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{grid_events2.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Reporting Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{grid_events} 
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{vmag.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{busVmag}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{vang.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{busVang}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{roc.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{ROC_phi}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[]{Simulated Grid Events and Associated Electrical Parameters}
\vspace{-7pt}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer. We can't test it and consequently confirm your findings. The code fragment from your question using example images provided by `graphicx` package doesnt exhibits problem you mentioned. So, source of your problem is not in your code fragment.

Comment: BTW, using your "solution " push figure above top text border. To see this, insert `` in MWE in my answer and you will see, that your solution only cause new problem.

Answer (score 0):

To long for the comment:

Since you not provide MWE (Minimal Working Example, a small but complete document,) which reproduce your problem, we cannot identified source of your problem. Using your code sniped in MWE with `article` document class *does not* reproduce your problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]%[htbp!]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{grid_events2.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Reporting Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{grid_events}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{vmag.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{busVmag}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{vang.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{busVang}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.485\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{roc.pdf}
   \caption{Scenario 2 - Data Rate of vPMUs}
   \label{ROC_phi}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[]{Simulated Grid Events and Associated Electrical Parameters}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Above MWE produce:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you see, your problem is not reproducible.